# XNA/C# Shadows look strange in orthographic

Tags: xna, c#, directx, shadows

I have implemented shadows in to my game engine. They look fine when rendered in projection mode as a projected light, however I get a strange "blocky" look when they are put into orho'. I will be rendering much bigger scenes (MMO size maps, for example) and Ive heard that rendering in orthographic for the shadow map will give a better result, and it does in some ways. I dislike rendering with projective perspective as you can see the view frustum, whereas this doesnt happen with orthographic.

Here is the code I have for rendering every update:

```
    public void UpdateLightData()
    {
        Matrix lightsView;
        Matrix lightsProjection; 
        ambientPower = 0.2f;
        lightPower = 2f;

        cameraFrustum.Matrix = player.view * player.projection;
        lightPos = new Vector3(0, 30, 0);
        lightsView = Matrix.CreateLookAt(lightPos, new Vector3(-2, 3, -10), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        lightsProjection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(Globals.device.Viewport.Width, Globals.device.Viewport.Height, 0.1f, 100f);
        //lightsProjection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver2, 1f, 5f, 100f);

        lightsViewProjectionMatrix = lightsView * lightsProjection;
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of ProjectionPerspective:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yen671frsft4kdl/Screenshot%202015-03-07%2016.00.32.png?dl=0

Here is what it looks like in orthographic:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jj6h4zgodda38fe/Screenshot%202015-03-07%2016.01.19.png?dl=0

Comment: It's usually the other way around, you get blocky shadows with a perspective projection since precision distribution is biased based on distance. The only difference I see between those screenshots is that one of them is _obviously_ incorrectly filtered. You appear to be linearly filtering the depth texture, which will round the edges of shadows. To properly filter shadows, you need to perform multiple depth *tests* instead of a single depth test using the average of multiple depths; sort of the opposite of regular texture filtering.

Comment: The orthographic projection matrix you've made has set 1 pixel = 1 unit in scale. That's likely way too small to get the resolution you want.

Comment: @Andon How would I go about doing multiple tests and what would this look like in code. I can provide my HLSL effect file if necessary

Comment: @mklingen How could I change this scale to get a better resolution and as mentioned I can provide the HLSL code. I basically want the precision of a projective shadow map but without the view frustum so that its like the orthographic in that sense

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw: You take 4+ samples using _point sampling_, do 4 independent depth tests and then average the pass/fail result. The fundamental concept is known as Percentage Closer Filtering, instead of rounding hard edges, it softens them by providing shadows that don't 100% pass/fail. You can actually do this automatically if you use a texture lookup that includes comparison (e.g. `SampleCmp`).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Is this the easiest way to achieve what Im after? I like everything about perspective view, I just want everything outside of frustum to not be as dark as the shadows. If there's a way to do that, that would be much better for me. Thank you

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I have done some research today and apparently I could clamp the edges of the lights frustum and set it to a color, this was in opengl though :( Would there be a way to do this in XNA

Comment: Direct3D has clamp to border texture addressing as well. I'm not really keen on how to use it (how to set the texture's border color, that is), but I know it's there.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I found this link to an article about shadow mapping specifically to the code I am using (from the same tutorial). Some how he has managed to color the outsude of frustum a red color. This is the sort of effect I'm after it that helps at all. Link to the article: http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~powerk/xna/shading/ShadowMapping.html
It also states that clamping is already enabled with that specific example of code :)